# Adobe AIR sample applications?

Tags: air, adobe, sample

I just started to learning the Adobe AIR. I think I would learn quite fast by referring the sample applications. Can you let me know any Adobe AIR open source applications?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Over 20 example apps (from Adobe):

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/samples_actionscript.html

> The following sample applications will help you get started using Adobe AIR. These are basic applications built by Adobe engineers to demonstrate the capabilities of the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

There are 75 air samples here http://code.google.com/p/jsairsamples/

Answer (score 1):

You can thousands of code samples, implementation in the Tour De Flex app. This app is like a documentation and also a component library which shows small code implementation of what the components displayed can do. 
You can get it [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html).